# System.IO.File.Copy() produces System.IO.IOException: The specified network name is no longer available

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, .net

I have a windows service (C# .Net 3.5) that grabs data from a network share and does a copy to the host of the service.

The size of the data copied ranges from 50KB to 750MB, and the number of files copied varies.  In perhaps 20% of the copies I am getting System.IO.IOException: The specified network name is no longer available.

My google-fu is failing to turn up an answer as to what might cause this during a File.Copy.  Has anyone seen/solved this before?

Here is the recursive method that does the copy.  The exception occurs on line File.Copy(fromFile, toFile, overwrite);

```
private static int RecursiveCopyDirectory(string from, string to, bool merge, bool overwrite, int depth)
    {
        depth++;

        if (!from.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()))
        {
            to += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
        }
        if (!to.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()))
        {
            to += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("RecursiveDirectoryCopy( {0}, {1}, {2} )", from, to, merge));
        if (Directory.Exists(to))
        {
            if (!merge)
            {
                return (int)EventEnum.FileSystemError_DirectoryAlreadyExists;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(to);
        }

        string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(from);

        foreach (string fromDirectory in directories)
        {
            string [] fromDirectoryComponents = fromDirectory.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
            string toDirectory = to + fromDirectoryComponents[fromDirectoryComponents.Length - 1];
            RecursiveCopyDirectory(fromDirectory, toDirectory, merge, overwrite, depth);
        }

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(from);

        foreach (string fromFile in files)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fromFile);
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0}", to + fileName));    
            string toFile = to + fileName;

            File.Copy(fromFile, toFile, overwrite);
        }

        return (int)EventEnum.GeneralSuccess;
    }
```

Comment: 1st thought - simple networking issue, but some code could be helpful.

Comment: Some more searching has shown some people disabling digitally signed communication for both parties within the local security policy, but as this is on a domain, I don't know yet if that will be considered an 'acceptable' solution.

Comment: Does the same file that fails to copy the first time fail a second time?

Comment: FYI: Your first if statement adds a '\' to the 'to' variable instead of the 'from'. Also, you have a depth variable that you never use to guard against any maximum recursion level.

Comment: Does this service delete the file once copied? (or does some other process do this?)

Does this service run on more than one host? (are there competing IO processes that may seek the file opened by another process?)

Comment: As far as I can see it is not consistent on a single file. 
The service does delete the data once the entire copy is complete.
The service runs on multiple hosts, all of which are seeing this behavior, however, the hosts serve different disjoint client sets so it is not possible for two hosts to compete for the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the customer that was using this software was running two instances of it simultaneously, against the same data set.  Once the redundant instance was stopped it resolved the error.  Thanks everyone who answered.

Answer (score 4):

File.Copy() opens up underline streams. You might have lost connection while File.Copy() is in progress. So, it can't flush and close the stream.

One possibility to recover from this, is to use the FileStream class and
call `Win32 API CloseHandle when such exception occurs`, doing so will release
the OS file handle so you can re-open the file.

```
[ DllImport("Kernel32") ]
public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

FileStream fs;
try {
...
}

catch(IOException)
{
// If resource no longer available, or unable to write to.....
if(...)
CloseHandle(fs.Handle);
}
```

Also, [MSDN recommends not to rely on `overwrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx). `Try deleting existing file and creating new one when copying them.`

```
File.Copy(..., ..., TRUE) does not work properly.

Be very careful with this method, as the Overwrite = True does NOT work properly.

I had an existing destination file that had some information inside it that was somehow preserved and carried over to the source file that was supposed to copy over it.  This should be impossible, but I confirmed it for myself.
```

Comment: @Priyank The MSDN recommendation link does not say anywhere not rely on overwrite and use delete + copy instead. Can you please recheck if the link you provided is not updated or can you provide any reason for the same. ( i am also facing similar error)

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to indicate that the network connection is lost partway through and probably isn't to do with the code at all. If the same folder copy succeeds sometimes and fails other times then this would back up that it's not the code to blame and must be a resource access issue.

Comment: We are looking into this, but so far it does not look like connectivity is lost.